# Azure Event Hub with multiple listeners

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, event-driven

Is it possible to have an Azure Event Hub with multiple listeners in the same application?
What I'm looking for is to trigger an event to a single hub and have two Azure Functions listen to it so they can both perform a task based on the same event.

I've implemented this at the minute with "Consumer Groups" but this feels wrong as I feel that this should be used when you have multiple applications reading the events.

Is there a better mechanism of doing this or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  The general answer for the best approach to doing so is "it depends on your application".  In the scenario that you're describing, you'll need to use two separate consumer groups due to how the Azure Functions bindings work.

Internally, the Function bindings use an event processor which will attempt to collaborate with other processors working against the consumer group to share work and prevent two instances reading from the same partition.  The same collaboration would take place if you were hosting one of the event processor types in your application as well.

For the other consumer types available in the Event Hubs SDK, working against the same consumer group is not a problem so long as you have less than the documented [quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas#common-limits-for-all-tiers). *(at the time of writing, this was 5 consumers per group)*

Comment: Going down the Consumer Group route, that could potentially have massive cost implications? On a Standard pricing model, you’re limited to 20 Consumer Groups but that is on a namespace level. So if I had a new Consumer Group for every event that needed a second listener then I’d quickly run out of Consumer Groups. It feels odd that I would be so limited by something that is meant to be a publish subscribe model.

Comment: Absolutely; if you're scaling out to a number of consumers, I'd recommend considering other patterns or options.   Avoiding the bindings and using the consumer client in an HTTP-triggered function called by Event Grid comes to mind.   The same basic approach would work having one function listen to the Event Hub and then call other HTTP-triggered functions.   Depending on scale, it may also be worth considering Service Bus with Topics/Subscriptions or a claim-check pattern using Blob Storage with an Event Grid trigger.   Each, of course, comes with its own additional complexity and trade-offs.

Comment: As I read it, you have 20 Consumer Groups per event hub, not per namespace in the Standard pricing: it says "Number of consumer groups per event hub" - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas

Comment: You're correct.   Apologies; that's my error.